# Pause all videos in iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video-embedding

I'm using `iframe` to embed a **mp4** video from **S3**.

```
<iframe class="you1" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vidcuratorfx2training/Video+1.mp4"></iframe>
```

But this video is auto playing when loaded. Since there are multiple videos on the page, all videos starts playing automatically.

I tried to pause all videos using below **js** code but it's not working.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (var i = 0; i< frames.length; i++) {
            var innerDoc = (frames.item(i).contentDocument) ? 
                frames.item(i).contentDocument : frames.item(i).contentWindow.document;
            var iframeVideoTags = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("video");
            for (var j = 0; j < iframeVideoTags.length; j++) {
                iframeVideoTags.item(j).pause();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My CSS constraints are limiting to use HTML5 video tag. I need to used iframe only.

**How to load iframe videos paused by default?**

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

> But using above code, you need to add two different format of video
>   for different browser support.

My best suggestion would be upload your video on youtube and add the youtube link to your "**iFrame's src**". the advantages of using youtube url is that youtube handle all the possibilitis like you minimize the screen and others